# Most pythonic way to handle a possibly empty gzip file?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a process that checks for new data, and if it finds any, writes it out to a file.  I think have a process that loads the file to `Amazon S3` and then `Redshift`.  It is fully possible, and even likely, that sometimes there will be no new data returned.  I want to find a Pythonic way to avoid the load to S3/Redshift if no data was written to the file.

Since my code heavily uses `generators`, I don't really have a way of knowing ahead of time if there is any data returned.  Here is the block of code:

```
with gzip.open(outfile, 'wt') as outf:
        writer = DictWriter(
            f=outf,
            fieldnames=fieldnames,
            extrasaction='ignore',
            delimiter='|',
            escapechar='\\'
        )
        ...attempt to pull data
if stat(outfile).st_size > 0:
    mu.load_to_rs(
            outfile=outfile,
            s3_path='github_scripts/github_commits',
            table_name=table,
            truncate=True # change for prod
        )
else:
    logger.info('The load file size was 0 bytes: terminating.')
```

As you can see, I tried to check for the `os.stat.st_size` of the file, but a `gzip`ped file isn't 0 bytes.  What is the most pythonic way to handle this type of problem?

Comment: If the file is empty (although gzipped is not 0 bytes) it shouldn't take much processing time to peek into the file to see how many bytes/lines are inside... I'm not sure how else you'd know that it's empty, unless all gzipped empty files are the same (nonzero) size, then check for that size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make an empty gzip file and see what it looks like:

```
In [3]: import gzip

In [12]: with gzip.open('empty.gz', 'wb') as f:
    ...:     f.write(b'')
    ...:     

In [13]: with open('empty.gz', 'rb') as f:
    ...:     contents_empty = f.read()
    ...:     

In [14]: contents_empty
Out[14]: b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08,P\xccX\x02\xffempty\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

In [15]: len(contents_empty) - len('empty')
Out[15]: 21
```

So an empty gzip file has a size of 21 bytes plus the length of the file's name without extension.

**Edit**: According to the [file format specification](http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#file-format), the last four bytes in the file contain the size of the original data modulo 2^32.

```
In [19]: contents_a[-4:], contents_b[-4:]
Out[19]: (b'\x00\x04\x00\x00', b'\x00\x04\x00\x00')

In [21]: '{:04x}'.format(1024)
Out[21]: '0400'
```

So if you opened the file in binary mode, you could `seek` to four bytes from the end and then read four bytes. That would give you the data size as well.

Comment: I ended up just writing a small function to open a gzipped file and check for content, but this would be equally valid!